# Difference between Cross GCC and Linux GCC toolchain

Tags: c++, eclipse, toolchain

While creating new C++ Project in Eclipse, I am being asked about toolchain.

What is the practical difference between these toolchains - `Cross GCC` and `Linux GCC`. In what circumstances use them? Does it have something to do with whether the project is going to be compiled both on linux and windows machines?

In [one of the answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76626/38919) we can read:

> Generally a cross compiler is a compiler producing code for a different kind of system than yours.

so if I compile project on target machine using own makefiles, it does not matter what option I will choose here, right?

Comment: Cross GCC means that you are compiling your project for a different architecture, e.g. you have a x86 processor and want to compile for ARM. Linux GCC just means the standard GCC

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Cross compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) article on wikipedia is quite good. Generally a cross compiler is a compiler producing code for a different kind of system than yours. Usually this means a different target hardware architecture, but it can also mean a different target operating system (or both).

Theoretically you could combine these and use a cross-compiler on architecture A<sub>1</sub> and operating system S<sub>1</sub> to build a cross-compiler that would run on architecture A<sub>2</sub> under operating system S<sub>2</sub> and produce code for operating system S<sub>3</sub> on architecture A<sub>3</sub>.

As Ulrich mentions in his comment, Linux GCC should be your "native" compiler (i.e. for the same target).